# elasticsearch with range sub query in nested query

Tags: elasticsearch, subquery

I am trying to get a nested query filter inside of a nested.

here is my es mapping: there is one "id" field(long) and a nested field called "my_field" with four sub fields in it.

```
{
    "my_index": {
        "mappings": {
            "dynamic": "strict",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "my_field": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "x": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "y": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "z": {
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        "a": {
                            "type": "double"
                        },
                        "b": {
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how to retrive the document with nested es query which contains sub range query in it.
For example, I'm trying to get two document id :11111 and id:22222 with nested query restriction "x > 15" or "a > 0.5" and also with inner hit size limitation, which is 20 here.

```
{
    "_source": false,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "nested": {
                        "inner_hits": {
                        "size": 20
                     },
                     "path": "my_field",
                     "query": {
                         "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {
                                    "range": {
                                        "x": {
                                            "from": 15,
                                            "include_lower": true,
                                            "include_upper": true,
                                            "to": null
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "range": {
                                        "a": {
                                            "from": 0.5,
                                            "include_lower": true,
                                            "include_upper": true,
                                            "to": null
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ] 
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "should": [
                {
                    "term": {
                         "id": 11111
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "id": 22222
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "timeout": "5000ms",
    "track_total_hits": true
}
```

However, there are no hits return

Answer (score 0):

Please use the dot notation in your query to include the complete path, e.g.,

```
"range": {
  "my_field.x": { "from": ... }
}
```